# NodeJS MongoDB Pass parameter in the aggregation pipeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregation-framework, mean-stack

How to pass an parameter to the aggregation?
I'm getting the params and trying to pass it using `$match` operator but query returns empty array:

```
app.get('/api/:name', function(req, res){
        var name = req.params.name;
        console.log(name);

        db.collection('coll').aggregate([{$match: {name: '$name'}}, {$unwind: { path: "$dates", includeArrayIndex: "idx" } }, { $project: { _id: 0, dates: 1, numbers: { $arrayElemAt: ["$numbers", "$idx"] }, goals: { $arrayElemAt: ["$goals", "$idx"] }, durations: { $arrayElemAt: ["$durations", "$idx"]}}}]).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                assert.equal(null);
            }
            else {
                console.log(docs);
                res.json(docs);
            } 
        });
    })
```

Should I care about order of the operators in pipeline?

Comment: Try `{$match: {name: name}}`. `name` variable is in the scope so we just use javascript to reference it in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:-

```
app.get('/api/:name', function(req, res){
    var name = req.params.name;

    var query = [{$match: {'name': name}}, {$unwind: { path: "$dates", includeArrayIndex: "idx" } }, { $project: { _id: 0, dates: 1, numbers: { $arrayElemAt: ["$numbers", "$idx"] }, goals: { $arrayElemAt: ["$goals", "$idx"] }, durations: { $arrayElemAt: ["$durations", "$idx"]}}}];

    db.collection('coll').aggregate(query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            assert.equal(null);
        }
        else {
            console.log(docs);
            res.json(docs);
        } 
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you never use variable called name.

Try this, change `{$match: {name: '$name'}`  to `{$match: {name: name}`.

Answer (score 1):

try,
{$match: {'name': req.params.name}}
this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose does not cast pipeline stages. The below will not work unless _id is a string in the database

```
new Aggregate([{ $match: { _id: '00000000000000000000000a' } }]);
// Do this instead to cast to an ObjectId
new Aggregate([{ $match: { _id: 
mongoose.Types.ObjectId('00000000000000000000000a') } }]);
```

API URL: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate